# Phase diagram method

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-equations, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, phase-diagram

I was trying to find the famous attractor solution of the inflaton field which follows the equation

$$\frac{d\dot{\phi}}{d\phi}=-\frac{\sqrt{12\pi}(\dot{\phi}^2+m^2\phi^2)^{1/2}\dot{\phi}+m^2\phi}{\dot{\phi}}$$

in ''Physical Foundations of Cosmology
 by Viatcheslav Mukhanov'' the author claims the equation can be studied using the phase diagram method and the behavior of the solutions
in the $\phi$-$\dot{\phi}$ plane is shown in Figure 5.3

[image]

How does one reached such a plot? I tried solving the differential equation using Wolfram Mathematica but it couldn't generate a single point.

Comment: Hint: Linearize.

Answer (score 2):

Just write it as a vector field instead of a line-field:
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\phi}{dt} = \dot{\phi}\\
&\frac{d\dot{\phi}}{dt}  = - \,m^2\phi \, - \, \sqrt{12\pi(\dot{\phi}^2+m^2\phi^2)\,}\, \dot{\phi}
\end{align}
and run something simple like Runge-Kutta.
I basically, renamed the variables $x = \phi$ and $y = \dot{\phi}$ and rewrote the renamed vector field:
\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt} = y\\
&\frac{dy}{dt}  = - \,m^2\,x \, - \, \sqrt{12\pi(y^2+m^2x^2)\,}\, y
\end{align}
In Wolfram alpha (online Mathematica), I set up m = 3, then I just typed

```
StreamPlot[{y; - 3^2*x - sqrt(12*pi*(y^2 + 3^2*x^2))*y}, {x, - pi/8, pi/8}, {y, -5/sqrt(12*pi), 5/sqrt(12*pi)}]
```

and got the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with :

$\frac{d}{d\varphi}\left(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}$

thus:

$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)=\frac{d^2\varphi}{dt^2}$

you get this differential equation:

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{t}^{2}}}\varphi  \left( t \right)+ \sqrt 
{12\,\pi }\,\pm\,\sqrt { \left( {\frac {d}{dt}}\varphi  \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+{m}^{2} \left( \varphi  \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}}{
\frac {d}{dt}}\varphi  \left( t \right) +{m}^{2}\varphi  \left( t
 \right) 
=0$$
because the square-root   function you have two solution, one for plus square-root and one for minus square-root.

there is no analytical solution but you can solve it numerically

[image]

[image]

Maple code

[image]

Comment: Please let me know how did you solve it numerically. My attempts with Wolfram Mathematica have failed.

Comment: I use Maple Program to do the Simulation,  Which error you get?

Comment: I'm getting "step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected" Maybe there is a better way to do it than using NDSolve. I'll try Maple anyway.

Comment: I add the Maple code for you